# Including Missing DLLs

Tags: dll, runtime, directx

I am developing in DX 10/11, & when I tried the code on another computer with a NV 660, it said that d3dx11d_43 was not found. I reinstalled the **Visual C++ 2012 32/64 bit** & **DirectX Runtime**, but still says that. I think that the user needs to install the SDK or something.

I get the warning that the debug info cant be found.
From what I have reading, it is because I have something that depends on something debug related. No idea what though.

Is there a way to make the game compile with most, if not all, of the DLLs? I dont mind the extra size. The content of many games out-weigh the extra DLLs that are used.

I did compile as Release.

**Edit:**
Removed 1st question, since no one answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the dlls you need to the resource file, then compile the resource file to your exe file, and at last, parse the resource file at run time to get the dlls you need. here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808467/embed-dll-in-mfc-c-exe), you can take a look.

Comment: Neither the d3d11 runtime or elements of the SDK are licensed for redistribution in this way so allthough they very likely won't microsoft could in theory prosecute you for illegally distributing their copyrighted material. You need to build a release version (or install the SDK on the other machine if you _really_ need the debug dlls to work)

Comment: That's not true, the run-time library under redist folder of the SDK is permit to redistribute, please see my answer in this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926493/directx-game-with-no-prerequisite-software-to-run/12926765#12926765

Comment: I believe there are conditions on how you may distribute them though, but I might be wrong. I apologise if my comment is not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

d3dx11d_43 is a debug version of d3dx11_43 which your program links with when you do a debug build rather than a release build. The debug version is not included in the directx runtime installer, only in the SDK.

The license does not allow you to distribute it either.

You should build and distribute release versions of the code, or else require users to install the SDK which probably wouldn't be so popular!